# How to change the field value as Red color when end date is less than current date on field?

Tags: python, methods, odoo, odoo-8

I want to change the field value as red color when end date is less than current date on field ? I have field name followup_date, If Follow up Date has passed then it should be marked as Red on Grid. The method will create previous date is less than current date, but i have no idea how to write this method?  How is this possible? Can anyone help me out? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Show the code that you have tried

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048895/change-a-field-value-within-an-if-statement-in-odoo-8?rq=1

Comment: i did not try any code yet, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by this, its working for me now.

```
<tree string="Claims" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="colors">red:followup_date &lt; current_date;</attribute>
</tree>

<field name="stage_id" position="after">
  <field name="followup_date" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="current_date" invisible="1"/>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

If by grid you mean a One2many table. Here is an example that may help you.

```
<tree colors="red:followup_date < current_date">
    <field name="followup_date"/>        
</tree>
```